# Keyboard hook does not wait for SendMessage?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-hook

I need to block keys from a certain input device and I use a keyboard hook to do that, here it the hook function

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (SendMessage(targetWindow, WM_HOOK, wParam, lParam)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

because the keyboard hook is not able to receive the device handle, I use windows messaging system to message to a custom case called `WM_HOOK`, this case `PeekMessage` the `WM_INPUT` to see which device handle from `RAWINPUT` is creating the input, then returns an integer as it is the device handle that keys should be blocked or not

the whole hook works correctly except when I use `SendMessage`, the keydown event will be produced no matter what, the function waits for the return and does not execute anything until there is a return from message (tested with `std::cout`) but when I'm using `SendMessage` in my hook the keydown event is being produced even when hook returns 1, So I have no idea what causes this behavior.
the whole program is in the same process and communication of 2 functions are successful but windows is not waiting for hook when messaging is involved and I don't know what causes it?

Comment: Is the targetWindow in the same process? If not you can't use the pointers in the other process, that receives the message....

Comment: _tested with `std::cout`_ Logging with `OutputDebugString` might be better, it is less invasive.

Comment: @xMRi yeah, all the things that are happening in the program is in the same process

Comment: @PaulSanders does it really matter? both are printing into console, one just gets compiled only in debugger mode, which both print when they get executed, plus I said it just to show how I know the function is waiting

Comment: @xMRi I have tested if message is being received or not, actually communication is successful it's just windows not waiting for keyboard hook when messaging is involved, and I don't know what causes that

Comment: According to [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc#remarks), *If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook* and *The maximum timeout value the system allows is 1000 milliseconds (1 second)*.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thanks, It's not because of timeout, the time it takes is way below that even when hook is not waiting for message result but message is there, this happens, actually during this time I have started testing with messaging system and hook, and figured out WH_KEYBOARD_LL is queuing WH_INPUT before callback, so triggering the messaging system causes the queued Message to pass on causing to ignore the result of the call back, so best way to don't make input lag and decide based on device ID and key entered with ability to block a key, is an Upper filter driver